# CruiseControl.Net error: Unknown plugin for <msbuild>

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to get CruiseControl.Net working with MSBuild (this is my first exposure to CruiseControl.Net).  I thought I'd done the configuration correctly, however I just get the following error message when starting up:

```
[cc]Jun-22 20:02:55 Main          - error setting config file on controller
net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.CruiseControlException: error configuring project MyProject
        at *SNIP*
Caused by: net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.CruiseControlException: Unknown plugin for: <msbuild>
        at *SNIP*
[cc]Jun-22 20:02:55 Main          - error configuring project MyProject
```

As far as I can work out, this would appear to indicate that I'm missing the MSBuild plugin, however all documentation that I can find indicates that the MSBuild plugin has been included with CruiseControl.Net since version 1.0

- I'm using the latest binary release (v 2.8.3)
- Here is my config xml:

  ```
  <project name="MyProject">
    <listeners>
      <currentbuildstatuslistener file="logs/${project.name}/status.txt"/>
    </listeners>
    <bootstrappers></bootstrappers>
    <modificationset quietperiod="10">
      <filesystem folder="C:\snip\main"/>
    </modificationset>
    <schedule interval="60">
      <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>C:\snip\main</workingDirectory>
        <projectFile>MyProject.sln</projectFile>
        <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Debug /v:diag</buildArgs>
        <targets>Build;Test</targets>
        <timeout>900</timeout>
        <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
      </msbuild>
    </schedule>
    <log />
    <publishers />
  </project>
  ```

Any advice on how I can troubleshoot this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggg - it appears that I have unwittingly downloaded [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/), instead of [CruiseControl.Net](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) (and to make things even more confusing I was looking at CruiseControl.Net documentation)